# Yeoman webapp errors on default build

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I'm using the webapp generator and I'm getting errors on a default build.
I create a new directory and run

```
yo webapp
```

Then

```
grunt
```

And finally

```
grunt server:dist
```

The Chrome console gives me the following errors:

```
Allo 'Allo! a53234b6.main.js:3
Running jQuery 1.10.2 a53234b6.main.js:3
Failed to load resource http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:9000/modules/a53234b6.main.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for: a53234b6.main
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror skitch.js:354
```

Am I using the wrong commands? Do I need to update node, npm, yeoman, etc? This is an awesome tool, but I might need to switch back to manual mode b/c I can't troubleshoot it very well

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`, under `devDependencies`, add the following:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    ...
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    ...
    "grunt-contrib-livereload": "0.1.2", // <- add this line
```

Then:

```
$> npm install
$> bower install
$> grunt server
```